# Iterating over json objects from file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a file with multiple json objects, single object can span multiple
lines. How do I iterate over all objects in a file using nodejs.

**Background**: I am monitoring a service using REST api, and writing it stats to a file continuously over a period of time. I want to process that file and plot graph of various parameters.

Example

```
{
  "items" : 534,
  "latency" : 23,
  "errors": 4
}
{
  "items" : 493,
  "latency" : 22,
  "errors": 3
}
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file actually looks like that, (like several JSON files concatenated in a single file), then you are doing it wrong.

Just change it, so the file becomes an array that contains the different objects, so it looks something like this:

```
[
   {
      "items" : 534,
      "latency" : 23,
      "errors": 4
   },
   {
      "items" : 493,
      "latency" : 22,
      "errors": 3
   }
]
```

Then you could use regular methods to iterate arrays:

```
var objects = require('./your_json_file.json');

objects.forEach(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj.items);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, This approach did worked, I had to change my data collection to script to save data in array format.